# Checking an event only in one page of the app in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

i'm developing my first app in angular 4.0.

My problem is pretty simple but i would like to know if there is a best practice to solve my issue.

I have an header with position: 'fixed' and when the user scrolls the page this element changes some of its properties (height, background-size..) by adding a 'small' class dynamically.

This is my component

```
import {Component, OnInit, HostListener} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-header',
  templateUrl: './my-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  scrollState: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.scrollState  = false;
  }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  toggleScrollState() {
    if(window.pageYOffset == 0){
      this.scrollState  = false;
    }
    else{
      this.scrollState  = true;
    }
  }

}
```

and this the html

```
<header class="bk-blue clearfix" [ngClass]="{small: scrollState}">
  <a class="sx" href="#">Login</a>
  <a class="dx arrow-down"></a>
  <a class="dx" href="#">It</a>
</header>
```

Everything works fine but **this should happen only in the home page**. In the other page the header element should already be in the 'small' state without any DOM manipulations based on the scroll event.

I was thinking of checking the current route to set an additional variable (false if the current route matches the home page path, true otherwise) and put that in OR with scrollState. Something like this:

```
 <header class="bk-blue clearfix" [ngClass]="{small: notHome || scrollState}">
```

By doing so, however, i can't avoid calling the listener with its   implications in term of reduced performance.

What is for you the best approach to avoid calling the listener even in internal pages where it is not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

well, I would do this using [`ActivatedRouteSnapshot`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html)

```js
@Component({...})
class Header implements OnInit {
  readonly snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = null;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.snapshot = route.snapshot;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // if this.snapshot is HOMEPAGE
    // then
    // subscribe to the scroll and switch class when you need.
  }
}
```

You could also set a property on your `route.data` which tells you to animate or not the header.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeRouteComponent,
    data: { ANIMATE_HEADER: true }
  }
];

// header.ts
ngOnInit() {
  if(this.snapshot.data.ANIMATE_HEADER) {
    // do stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with the first implementation,  i cannot retrieve the url from the snapshot neither in the constructor or with ngOnInit(). I receive an empty array []

Comment: you should have everything there, but, also, try to have a look at `Router Events` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html

Comment: if i wrap the route.snapshot in a setTimeout i receive all the values expected but in ngOnInit or in the constructor all the values (also the custom data) are undefined